# ID: Cermetek DAA carrier board?

Tags: identification

Can anyone help identify this part? It appears to be a DAA module but on some kind of carrier board. I've emailed Cermetek but received no response. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: The DAA appears to be this one; http://www.cermetek.com/catalog/Telephone-Line-Interface/DataSheet/CH1817_607-0007.pdf The overall module is probably a 'smart' interface with a microcontroller.

Comment: @PeterSmith - Hi, That looks good enough to be an answer, to me!

Comment: It's not enough to give me a pinout for the carrier board, though.

Comment: @astronomerdave - Hi, "*It's not enough to give me a pinout for the carrier board*" True. However (a) No-one is saying that a *better* answer isn't possible. (b) IMHO *Peter Smith*'s comment is useful & an attempt to answer the question. It links to the DAA datasheet which seems to be new info (you didn't say you had that before) and that might be useful for future readers (comments have no revision history, unlike answers, and can be deleted for various reasons, leading to the loss of that link). (c) Even a pinout may not be enough to use the module, depending on what the IC (MCU?) does. YMMV

Comment: Right, sorry, I should have been more clear. I was able to Google the part number on the DAA; I was trying to identify the carrier board.

Comment: Have you tried peeling back the ID sticker on the (looks like) 28 pin DIP to see if there is a part number? That may or may not help but it would be more information.